# how to refresh recyclerview specific item view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView, it will show close icon in the last item view,
but when I add new data in the Adapter,
the old item does not refresh their view, it just adds new item view in the RecyclerView.

How could I update the old last item view?

I tried to use `notifyItemChanged(int)` but it didn't work.

```
for(int i = lastPosition(); i < mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1; i++) {
    mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(i);
}
```

Comment: did you updated `lastPosition()` ?

Comment: i have already update it...

Comment: Try replacing recyclerView adapter after mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(): 
recyclerView.swapAdapter(mAdapter, true);

Comment: Depending what you display that close icon? Position or something in your data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I have find the problem
the problem is not in adapter, it in my viewholder
my xml layout show the icon in default,

when it is the last item ,I set the icon Gone

```
public static void hideBottomLine(BaseViewHolder h) {
    h.line.setVisibility(View.GONE);   
}
```

when i notifyItemChanged it ,I thought it will show default, but not! So when I add method

```
public static void showLine(BaseViewHolder h) {
    h.line.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

now it work...

Answer (score 0):

Add below code after adding item in listview...

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: it can update adapter data, but it not update old  item onbindviewholder...

Answer (score 0):

you can call this whenever you want to update the item of recyclerview list

```
mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(ITEM_INDEX);

//ITEM_INDEX IS THE POSITION
```